# php fatal error while connecting it to database

Tags: php, mysql

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in
>   E:\newxmp\htdocs\schoolm\ss\service\mysqlcon.php:7 Stack trace: #0
>   E:\newxmp\htdocs\schoolm\ss\service\check.access.php(2):
>   include_once() #1 {main} thrown in
>   E:\newxmp\htdocs\schoolm\ss\service\mysqlcon.php on line 7

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely using PHP 7.x which has this function removed.

> Warning
>
> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed
>   in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be
>   used.

See http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: so what should i do to run that in php 7

Comment: You can't do anything to run it in PHP7. You have to rewrite your application to use PDO (or MySQLi). See the link @Nigel Ren posted for you.